# How to declare the interface of a NAMED function in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I can define the interface of a function:

```
interface Handler {
  (state: IState, action: IAction): IState;
}
```

Then I can declare a function that satisfies the interface:

```
let selectRegimen: Handler = function(state, action) {
  return state;
};
```

But what about named (as in, not anonymous) function? Obviously, I could do something like this:

```
let selectRegimen: Handler = function selectRegiment(state, action) {
  return state;
};
```

...but something feels strange about that syntax. Is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no way to force a specific name in a named function expression just like there's no way to force a specific variable name to assign the function to.

What you are doing is fine though you could use a type alias instead of an interface if you find that better suits your taste:

```
type Handler = (state: IState, action: IAction) => IState;
```

Answer (score 7):

FWIW I landed here looking to force a named function in a class by having it implement an interface.

To do this you can:

```
interface Handler {
    selectRegimen: (state: IState, action: IAction) => IState
}

class MyHandler implements Handler {
    selectRegimen (state: IState, action: IAction) {
        let newState: IState
        // ...
        return newState
    }
}
```

Comment: How would this look for a function without parameters?  `someName: (): string`  leads to a typescript error

Comment: `someName: () => string` . I made a syntax error originally.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
// This is where you define the function
export interface SomeInterfaceName{
    someFunctionName(someParamName: SomeParameterType): SomeReturnType;
}

// Somewhere on the code

// This is where you implement the function
const someObjectThatImplemntsTheInterface = {
    someFunctionName: function(someParamName: SomeType) {
      return SomeReturnType;
    }
} as SomeInterfaceName;

// or you can implement with arrow function

const someObjectThatImplemntsTheInterface1 = {
    someFunctionName: (someParamName: SomeType) => {
      return SomeReturnType;
    }
} as SomeInterfaceName;
```